# Is svn up possible for export

Tags: svn, svn-update, svn-checkout, svn-export

I have exported my code, using

```
 $ svn export https://URL ./folder_name
```

I want to update my working folder which folder_name,

```
 $ svn up
    Skipped '.'
    Summary of conflicts:
      Skipped paths: 1
```

Is update working on exported svn repo ?

If do `svn co` and then up is working.

Let me know,
Thanks

Comment: You can export again, but if you want to keep the folder up-to-date, then you might want to consider a working copy instead of exporting.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to export again. My working repo on server is changing. So to keep folder up to date, is checkout helpfull and update later..?

Comment: If you need to keep it up to date, then yes, checkout and then update. The reason you do an export is to get a clean, non-updateable copy of the repository contents *at that point*.